# How to Integrate Scanner into an Inherited Class in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, java.util.scanner

I want the user to input the values of schoolName, schoolType, openingHours, and schoolAddress (inherited from the Super Class) by themselves. How do I integrate Scanner input to achieve that? Thanks

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class PrimarySchools { 
    String address; 
    
    public PrimarySchools (String schoolAddress) { 
        address = schoolAddress; 
    } 

    public String getAddress () { 
        return address; 
    } 

    public void setAddress (String schoolAddress) { 
        this.address = schoolAddress; 
    } 
} 

class BandA extends PrimarySchools {
    String name;
    String type; 
    String opening;

    public BandA(String schoolName, String schoolType, String openingHours, String schoolAddress {
        super(schoolAddress);
        this.name = schoolName;
        this.type = schoolType;
        this.opening = openingHours;
    }
}

class BandB extends PrimarySchools {
    String name;
    String type; 
    String opening;

    public BandB (String schoolName, String schoolType, String openingHours, String schoolAddress) {
        super(schoolAddress);
        this.name = schoolName;
        this.type = schoolType;
        this.opening = openingHours;
   }
}

class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner schoolData = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] maxSchools = new String[30];
```

Comment: you can create `Scanner` class `object` and `call` in the `constructor`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, I'm still new to Java, and I'm not sure if I understand that fully. Could you please give an example. Apologies for the inconvenience

Comment: my pleasure... can you show the `PrimarySchools` class. Besides, kindly give a brief description on  `Integrate Scanner into an Inherited Class`?

Comment: I have added the PrimarySchools class to the initial code above, and the opening part of my Main class. What I want to achieve basically is using Scanner to input values into the elements of the extended classes

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve the problem?

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class PrimarySchools { 
        String address; 
        
        public PrimarySchools (String schoolAddress) {
            address = schoolAddress; 
        } 
        
        public PrimarySchools () {
            System.out.print("Address: ");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            address = sc.nextLine();
        } 
        
        public String getAddress () {
            return address; 
        } 
        public void setAddress (String schoolAddress) { 
            this.address = schoolAddress; 
        }
}
```

Whenever you create the `PrimarySchools` object with empty `constructor` it'll ask for the `addrerss` and store.

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    Scanner schoolData = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name = schoolData.next();
    String type = schoolData.next();
    String opening = schoolData.next();
    String address = schoolData.next(); 
    
    BandA a = new BandA(name, type, opening, address);
    
    String[] maxSchools = new String[30];
}
```

Comment: This makes sense to me, thanks. But how do I do same for the inherited classes BandA and BandB which have their own member variables that are not meant to be the same?

Comment: From exactly where you want to ask the user for inputs? from `main` method or from the `BandA` constructor?

Comment: From the main method, but if asking in the constructors, BandA and BandB also works, I'm open to that, however, I think I'm used to doing such in the main

Comment: now? you can either take `input` from user and store in `variable` or in the `array` and pass in the `constructor` while creating an `object`.

Comment: Array does not confirm if input was stored. When the program is run, upon termination it returns something like [Classname@135fbaa4]

Comment: `Classname@135fbaa4`it's the memory address of that particular class. However, what do you mean by _"Array does not confirm if input was stored"_? can you show the `array` approach please?

Comment: Pardon my poor use of the right Java terminologies. I have that sorted now. Thanks